How to find a pattern string that is split in multiple lines?
Edit: I'll be more specific in my question:
I'm trying to find a gene in a chromosome.
Chromosomes are a string of millions of characters long, and they're typically formatted into a .fasta file.
A .fasta file has a linebreak every 60-70 characters.
So, since a gene can be thousands of characters long, it surely will be spread along various lines in a fasta file.
An example: I'm looking for the pattern "GCCTTTTACT". In the fasta file it is spread across 2 lines:
GCTGTGCACCGCTGCAGTCTCATGAGCCGGGCTGCAGAACATCATGCGTCTGCTTCGCCT
TTTACTAAGCTAGACCAGTGGATTGCGGCCTATTTGAGCTCGCATCACGATTTTTCTGGG
A regular grep can't find it, and I expect the same output that a regular grep would give me: the input string and hopefully some neighboring lines. The neighborhood of a gene is important in my analysis.
All the topics already created in this matter take the pattern split in two parts as input, but I can't predict how my pattern will be split in a fasta file
The simplest solution I could conceive so far would be to reformat the whole fasta file to eliminate all the \n characters
using grep -Pzo didn't solve the matter
Once again, thank you for your time.

Does the linked duplicate answer your question?

Show the expected output. It is unclear whether you only want the string you are looking for or the entire line or just the file name containing the string.

Hello, friend. Thank you for your time analyzing my request. I'll be more specific.
